# Why doesn't this work to calculate proportion of mothers with educations at different levels?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm taking a python course on Coursera. For one of the assignments the question is:

Write a function called proportion_of_education which returns the proportion of children in the dataset who had a mother with the education levels equal to less than high school (<12), high school (12), more than high school but not a college graduate (>12) and college degree.

This function should return a dictionary in the form of (use the correct numbers, do not round numbers):

```
{"less than high school":0.2,
"high school":0.4,
"more than high school but not college":0.2,
"college":0.2}
```

I wrote a code that is probably rather inefficient but should work and I don't understand why I'm getting errors

Here it is:

```
def proportion_of_education():
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv.')
    df.loc[:,['SEQNUMC','EDUC1']]
    new_df = df.loc[:,['SEQNUMC','EDUC1']]
    new_df['middle'] = new_df['EDUC1']  == 1
    new_df['highed'] = new_df['EDUC1']  == 2
    new_df['lessthancollege'] = new_df['EDUC1']  == 3
    new_df['college'] = new_df['EDUC1']  == 4
    {"less than high school":new_df.middle[new_df.middle==True].count()/28465,
    "high school":new_df.highed[new_df.highed==True].count()/28465,
    "more than high school but not college":new_df.lessthancollege[new_df.lessthancollege==True].count()/28465,
    "college":new_df.college[new_df.college==True].count()/28465}


    
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

The course uses this to check it:

```
assert type(proportion_of_education())==type({}), "You must return a dictionary."
assert len(proportion_of_education()) == 4, "You have not returned a dictionary with four items in it."
assert "less than high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "more than high school but not college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
```

Now this is what I'm getting in return:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2eae51ff42e4> in <module>
----> 1 assert type(proportion_of_education())==type({}), "You must return a dictionary."
      2 assert len(proportion_of_education()) == 4, "You have not returned a dictionary with four items in it."
      3 assert "less than high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
      4 assert "high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
      5 assert "more than high school but not college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."

<ipython-input-1-57ea8a20b116> in proportion_of_education()
     16 
     17 
---> 18     raise NotImplementedError()

NotImplementedError:
```

Why am I getting these errors? What could I do to make this more efficient?

Comment: The last line of your function is `raise NotImplementedError()`. Why? Perhaps this was in a function template provided by the class? If so, you should remove it and return the dict instead.

Comment: I removed the raise NotImplementedError() line and it says You must return a dictionary. Is there an error in the way I am writing that?

Comment: You need to actually `return` something from the function. You do that with `return`

Comment: Thank you for your help! That worked. With regards to my second question is there a more efficient way to write a program for this? I feel like I went a roundabout way.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your second question, you may try:

```
import pandas as pd
def proportion_of_education():
    df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
    step1 = df['EDUC1'].value_counts()
    step2 = step1/len(df)
    step3 = step2.rename({
        1: 'less than high school',
        2: 'high school',
        3: 'more than high school but not college',
        4: 'college',
    })
    step4 = step3.to_dict()
    return step4
```

`step1` gives you the counts, while `step2` convert counts into percentage. Now `step2` is a `pd.Series` object, so you can do `step3` to rename `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` (which are the indices of the `pd.Series`) into what they mean, and the last step convert the `pd.Series` into a `dict`.

Below is a different version of the same process with less intermediate variables.

```
import pandas as pd
def proportion_of_education():
    df = pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv')
    
    return (df['EDUC1'].value_counts() / len(df)).rename({
        1: 'less than high school',
        2: 'high school',
        3: 'more than high school but not college',
        4: 'college',
    }).to_dict()
```